# Week number from Date format in excel(Monthwise_Week Number)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if there is a formula which can calculate week number from a date format in excel(week number for a month and not year)

Say i have generated data for 1st and 2nd week of may 2017

```
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
02/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
04/05/2017
04/05/2017
04/05/2017
04/05/2017
04/05/2017
05/05/2017
05/05/2017
05/05/2017
05/05/2017
05/05/2017
05/05/2017
05/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
08/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
09/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
10/05/2017
11/05/2017
11/05/2017
11/05/2017
11/05/2017
11/05/2017
11/05/2017
11/05/2017
11/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
12/05/2017
```

Now i want to assign a formula which can tell me week number for a month considering week starts at Monday and closes at Sunday.

Let me know if there is a way to do it. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `=WEEKNUM()`

More on the formula [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340)

Comment: @chef1075..thanks but i need to divide week based on month and not year

Comment: @KingshukChoudhury no worries. If the answer is correct tick the  "checkbox" so the question can be closed.